# Traveling to Europe during a short term stay in London

Tags: schengen, uk, schengen-visas

I will be visiting London for 3 weeks from India. During one of the two weekends, I would like to visit Paris. I have already obtained UK visa and have ample time to apply for Schengen visa. Kindly advise me what kind of itinerary and travel bookings I need to produce before French Consulate in India for the same. Since I am not UK resident, will my booking from London to Paris be considered legitimate for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

> Kindly advise me what kind of itinerary and travel bookings I need to produce before French Consulate in India.

The one you actually plan to follow.  Include your itinerary for the entire trip from India to London to Paris and back.

> will my booking from London to Paris be considered legitimate for this purpose?

Of course.  Tourists take trips that cover multiple countries all the time.  Include a copy of your UK visitor visa in your application.